# How to make a section of my string a different font and size then the rest

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

I am trying to make the letters ahc a bold version of courier while keeping the rest of the string the regular courier. the line of code I am talking about is in the upper_label variable.

right now on the tkinter interface, it displays

```
                 A Computer Science Glossary
                            by
                            ahc
```

but i want it to say

```
                A Computer Science Glossary
                            by
                            AHC <----- "i want that o be in bold"

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font



root = tk.Tk()

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH=600
#my_font=tk.Font("courie",weight="bold")


canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

upper_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="black")
upper_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0,relwidth=3,relheight=0.8,anchor="center")



upper_label= tk.Label(upper_frame,text="A Computer Science Glossary\nby\nahc",font="courie",fg="white", bg="black")
upper_label.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.5)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
lower_frame.place(relx=1,rely=1,relwidth=2,relheight=0.3, anchor="center")

bottom_label=tk.Label(lower_frame,text="click here to exit:", fg="white", bg="black")
bottom_label.place(relx=0,rely=0)

bottom_button = tk.Button(lower_frame, text= "Exit")
bottom_button.place(relx=0, rely=0.1,width=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new label and place it below the non bold label:

```
upper_label= tk.Label(upper_frame,text="A Computer Science Glossary\nby",font="courie",fg="white", bg="black")
upper_label.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.5)
tk.Label(upper_frame,text="ahc",font="courie 16 bold",fg="white", bg="black").place(relx=0.66,rely=0.6)
```